# I try to connect my self to outlook with pywin32 python but i don't want to use the application

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, pywin32

To be clear, i want to use this line of code
`outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")`
but i do not want to use the outlook application.
I want to connect myself to outlook.office365.com. Not to Outlook.Application because I have to use my code on Linux and Outlook application isn't on Linux.
But I still want to use  win32com because he reads very clearly email.

Can someone help me ? because I don't find how to do it !

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you are referring to is specific to the desktop edition of Outlook and Windows:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

You may consider using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) instead.

For the on-premise exchange accounts you may consider using EWS, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.